# Series expansion of reciprocal function of Generalized Exponential Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Generalized Exponential Integral of order p has a series expansion  http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19.10
Is there a series expansion of the reciprocal function ?

Comment: Around which point? In any case, you might be interested to look at the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Comment: Around Ep(0)=1/(p-1).